# got error TypeError: urlretrieve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'CablingFilename' python

Tags: python, url, dictionary, get, typeerror

i am trying to make a list from a txt file that is online, this is part of the code

```
import urllib

def Dict(Filename,var1,var2):
    FileDict = open(Filename,'r')

    List = []
    for l in FileDict:
        if D in l:
            pattern = re.split('W',l)
            List.append(pattern[4])
```

## more code...

```
    return (thing1,thing2,List)

in1=raw_input("name of file \n >")
url='https.page_address'

in2=raw_input("other instructions")
in3=raw_input("other instructions2")
urllib.urlretrieve(url+in1, Filename = in1)

MyDict = Dict(in1,in2,in3)
```

But when i execute the script and type in1 (name of file), i get the error "TypeError: urlretrieve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Filename' and i checked over and over but i do not know the error
hope somebody help, i am new at python so please dont be so hard
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword is lowercase `f`, 'filename' not Filename. 
`filename = uri`

Wrong way:

```
In [56]: import urllib

In [57]: in1 = "foo"

In [58]: urllib.urlretrieve("http://goo.gl/xymu6o",Filename=uri)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-e89982cacc95> in <module>()
----> 1 urllib.urlretrieve("http://goo.gl/xymu6o",Filename=in1)

TypeError: urlretrieve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Filename'
```

Correct way:

```
In [59]: import urllib

In [60]: 

In [60]: in1 = "foo"

In [61]: urllib.urlretrieve("http://goo.gl/xymu6o",filename=in1 )
Out[61]: ('foo', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7fb580d57680>)
```

Just change to `urllib.urlretrieve(url+in1, filename = in1)`

or   `urllib.urlretrieve(url+in1, in1)`

As you can see from the docs description:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])
```

You pass `url` which is required and optional, `filename` not `Filename`

`filename` is a keyword arg, you cannot use `Filename` as it is simply not a valid keyword argument.

Comment: what do you mean? it is just the name of file, and in all the script is written the same 'Filename'

Comment: Urlretrieve takes a keyword arg filename which specifies what to save the file as. You have Filename as the keyword arg which is not a valid keyword.  F and f are not the same in python.

Comment: sorry, i still dont understand, they are all writen with F,so, i have to change from F to f? i already did it but it is the same error

Comment: You only have to change it to filename in urlretrieve. You don't actually even need to use filename= as the second arg is filename by default

Comment: and how should i write it?? the user have to go to that page and choose a file from a list of files, thats why i wrote it like that,sorry, i used this in other script and it worked, thats why i do not know how to use your idea

Comment: if you mean it has to be urllib.urlretrieve(filename) i did it and it does not work, is the same error

Comment: this helped i changed the name of the file to cabfilename and wrote urllib.urlretrieve(url1+cablingfilename,cablingfilename) instead of the line in the question, thanks for your time